# DataTables: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of undefined

Tags: php, json, datatables

Here's my HTML:

```html
<table id="mens-clubs" class="display" cellspacing="0" role="grid" data-page-length="50">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="0">ID</th>
            <th width="20%">Club</th>
            <th width="20%">City</th>
            <th width="20%">State</th>
            <th width="20%">Metro</th>
            <th width="20%">Union</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th width="0">ID</th>
            <th width="20%">Club</th>
            <th width="20%">City</th>
            <th width="20%">State</th>
            <th width="20%">Metro</th>
            <th width="20%">Union</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Here's my JS:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mens-clubs').DataTable({
        'ajax': {
            'url': '/my/data/path/src.php',
            'dataSrc': 'data'
        },
        'columns': [
            { 'data': 'id' },
            { 'data': 'clubName' },
            { 'data': 'city' },
            { 'data': 'state' },
            { 'data': 'metroArea' },
            { 'data': 'unionName' }
        ],
        'processing': true,
        'dom': '<"row"<"small-24 column"B>><"row"<"large-8 columns"<"row filter-wrapper"<"columns small-24"f>>><"large-16 columns right"p>>' + 't' + '<"row"<"small-24 columns"p>>',
        'buttons': [ 'copy', 'excel', 'csv', 'pdf', 'print' ],
        'searching': true,
        'language': {
            'search': '',
            'searchPlaceholder': 'Search Clubs'
        },
        'pagingType': 'full_numbers',
        'scrollY': '50vh',
        'scrollCollapse': true,
        'deferRender': true
    });
});
```

Here are the contents of my `src.php` file:

```js
{
  "data": [{
    "id": "3",
    "clubName": "Alpha Steelers",
    "city": "Alpha",
    "state": "UT",
    "metroArea": "",
    "unionName": "Rocky Mountain"
  }, {
    "id": "5",
    "clubName": "Beta of Aspen",
    "city": "Beta",
    "state": "CO",
    "metroArea": "",
    "unionName": "Rocky Mountain"
  }, {
    "id": "6",
    "clubName": "Gamma Highlanders",
    "city": "Gamma",
    "state": "CO",
    "metroArea": "",
    "unionName": "Rocky Mountain"
  }]
}
```

My data file is successfully retrieved via `GET` every time, however, I get this error immediately following it's successful retrieval:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of undefined`

The line the error references inside DataTables.js is `79406`. It is inside the `_fnBuildAjax()` function and is as follows:

[image]

Has anyone ever come across this error or have any idea what this error is referring to? I've run my `src.php` file through `JSONLinter` and it is valid. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried console.log on json in the success call?

Comment: When I run this -- 
`'ajax': {
                'url': '/my/data/path/src.php',
                'dataSrc': 'data',
                'success': function(json){
                    console.log(json);
                }
            }`

It says `undefined`

Comment: The documentation isn't telling me what I expect to see with success... Can you try using replacing "success" with "done"?

Comment: Same error: `'ajax': { 'url': '/my/data/path/src.php', 'dataSrc': 'data', 'done': function(json){ console.log(json); } `

Comment: @DaveyJake  try this please.  In your success handler:  "console.log(arguments);"  This will return all parameters passed to the even if they aren't in the function definition.

Comment: @Aliester My apologies for not getting back to you sooner.  Inside my console, it returns `Arguments[3]` with my main `data` object being `Argument[0].data`.  Only question now is do I make `Arguments[0].data` my `dataSrc` value or how do I proceed?

Comment: @DaveyJake Sorry hit crunch time at work and haven't been on stackoverflow.  change your success handler function to this:  "function(data, ...)  { ... }"  the "..." portions are the rest of your arguments collection and function definition.  "Arguments[0]" is just the first parameter in the function definition.  So after that you just need to do "callback(data)"  assuming you are overriding the built in ajax function in the DataTable settings when you construct it.

Comment: @DaveyJake  Also not sure where your "error" object is in the Arguments list but it is generally best practice to use HTTP status codes and messages to convey errors so your error handler can handle it.  (something to keep in mind).  I always find it strange when you have to check for an "error" message in a "success" handler.  Just seems contradictory.

Answer (score 0):

Your json feed is missing some info. Jquery will send down a "draw" number and that needs to be fed back. You need the total and filtered as well as the data.

```
$complete = array("draw" => $this->request->query['draw'],
            'recordsTotal' => $total,
            "recordsFiltered" => $filtered,
            "data" => $output);
```

Comment: Same error. My src.php file looks like this:  `{
  "draw": 1,
  "recordsTotal": 3,
  "recordsFiltered": 3,
"data": [{
    "id": "3",
    "clubName": "Alpha Steelers",
    "city": "Alpha",
    "state": "UT",
    "metroArea": "",
    "unionName": "Rocky Mountain"
  }, {
    "id": "5",
    "clubName": "Beta of Aspen",
    "city": "Beta",
    "state": "CO",
    "metroArea": "",
    "unionName": "Rocky Mountain"
  }, {
    "id": "6",
    "clubName": "Gamma Highlanders",
    "city": "Gamma",
    "state": "CO",
    "metroArea": "",
    "unionName": "Rocky Mountain"
  }]
}`